# Laptop battery detected intermittently but power is supplied

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

**Situation**: Laptop battery detected sometimes, gives power always, when detected can be charged.

I wanted to ask what the problem could be and how to go about it. Battery is ThinkPad Battery 57++ (9 cell) - details in cli output.

It is `T540p`; it runs very well, I love it. However the battery every now and then is "not detected" despite continuing to provide power. I run linux on it, but I still have windows 10 installation on it as well and the problem is replicated there. As I typed up this post, the battery state changed twice - without interruption of power supply to laptop (it is not plugged in now). Couple of times last week laptop could not start/resume unless I plugged in power and removed battery and then started/resumed it.

When battery is in "not detected" state I can see charge "estimating" in gnome 3 panel and [tlp](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html) (Thinkpad Laptop Power Management) output is:

```
 tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (unsupported hardware)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1147
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  86580 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  86320 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =      0 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown (threshold effective)

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     96 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =    0.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   99.7 [%]
```

When battery is detected, I have this output:

```
tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (unsupported hardware)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1147
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  86580 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  86320 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  64130 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =  12127 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     96 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   74.3 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   99.7 [%]
```

I have changed the battery and the power adapter as well, since the old power adapter tended to emit clicking noise sometimes. I have updated the BIOS to the latest (right after that I heard the old charger clicking again - which I had not heard in a long time - and then I got the new one). Sometimes the battery changes state after tapping on the back of the battery pack in direction from right-to-left. Could it be one of the battery connector data pin sockets that has a problem? How can one troubleshoot this? I am still in a year's warranty from the seller.

Comment: If it is under warranty then claim on it.

Comment: Thought so, it is seller's warranty on e-bay still.